# What does Lotus Notes use to display HTML e-mails?

Tags: email, html, lotus-notes

I need to make a newsletter which looks well in Lotus Notes but I neither want to install evaluation version nor have a license for it.

Which web browser engines does latest Lotus Notes use to render HTML e-mails?
Does it use [trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) or [gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29) or something own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had serious problems with Lotus Notes Clients too when designing newsletters. It seems that it uses its own engine, which is probably years behind in development.

The best is to really write XHTML-conform markup and constrain everything within a fixed width table. Some old tips are to be found [here](http://www.templatekit.com/lotusnotes1.php) and something new is [here](http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/2010/01/23/09.27.00/?doing_wp_cron#step4), if you like a longer read.

Comment: Unfortunately both links are not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Notes, it most likely uses the "Trident" engine, but it's *HORRIBLY* modified and restricted.

There is a StackOverflow question that may also provide some help: [Sending HTML emails that renders correctly in Notes 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368587).

And if you're willing to spend a little money, look at this site: [Email Testing and Email Preview - EmailOnAcid](http://www.emailonacid.com/).  It's a test field for HTML emails.  Come to think of it, look even if you don't want to spend the money.  They have a good explanation for writing newsletters to fit most browsers, including mobile.